# scroll down to see the end of my page (under the ambulance image )

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**im working on an android app,and i want to scroll down to see the end of my page (under the ambulance image ),but the scroll bar doesnt move down,as you can see below in the image**

My app screenshot:
[image]

this is the part of my  activitymain.xml that could cause my scrolling problem  :

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/alphabet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/alphabet" />

          <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/essentials"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            android:src="@drawable/essentials" />

            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried nestedscrollview? I would also suggest to put an empty text box or something like that at the bottom of your layout. Change the font color and the background color of that box to your app background so you wouldn't see it but it's there and takes some space at the bottom. It's a hacky way to solve this issue but it works.

Comment: @blackslashn thanks dude,i used the nestedscrollview instead of scrollview and it's worked like magic !!!,you are my hero !!!!